# Android - Not allowed to start service Intent from JobIntentService: app is in background

Tags: java, android

I am receiving intents in a `BroadcastReceiver` and trying to start a service.

Since I am unable to run a service when the app is in background, I am trying to use a `JobIntentService` that would transport my intent to a normal service:

```
public class JsInvokerJobService extends JobIntentService {

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        // We have received work to do.  The system or framework is already
        // holding a wake lock for us at this point, so we can just go.
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing work: " + intent);
        this.startService(intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "Finished work: " + intent);
    }
```

however, this still crashes my app while in background with an error:

`Not allowed to start service Intent  app is in background`

I have read about using `Runnable` for these cases, but I can't figure out how to pass my context to a Runnable:

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    
    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        // We have received work to do.  The system or framework is already
        // holding a wake lock for us at this point, so we can just go.
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing work: " + intent);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                this.startService(intent);
            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "Finished work: " + intent);
    }
```

how do I access the context (obviously `this` won't work anymore)? and how do I pass the intent?

And will this work anyway? Or there is another method to it?

Comment: Why you want to start a service from onHandleWork() ? Do your work in onHandlework() itself.

Comment: I am working with React Native and I need to start a headless JS task that would perform a lot of logic (access local storage, make some networking calls, etc). As far as I understand this could only be done using a normal service. see https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android